# How do I fail a test in Jest when an uncaught promise rejection occurs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm working on adding test coverage to a Node project I'm working on using Jest. The code I'm testing is throwing errors within promises resulting in an `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` message being logged to the console.

While writing tests, I can pretty easily identify these issues and resolve them, but these warnings aren't actually causing Jest to mark the tests as failed, so our CI won't catch it. I've searched around for any suggestions and haven't found much.

I did find in Node's documentation that you can catch these warnings and handle them...

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', (error) => {
  throw error; // Or whatever you like...
});
```

So it seems like it would be pretty straightforward to add this code into my test cases. After all, an `Error` thrown within the test *should* cause the test to fail...

```
describe('...', () => {
  it('...', () => {
    process.on('uncaughtRejection', (error) => {
      throw error;
    });

    // the rest of my test goes here
  });
});
```

Unfortunately the behavior I'm seeing is that the error *does* get thrown, but Jest doesn't catch it and fail the test. Instead, Jest crashes with this error and the tests don't continue to run. This isn't really desirable, and seems like incorrect behavior.

Throwing an error outside of the `uncaughtRejection` handler works as expected: Jest logs the thrown error and fails the test, but doesn't crash. (i.e. the test watcher keeps watching and running tests)

Comment: Have you looked into the docs with regards to expect.toThrow()? 
https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/expect.html#tothrowerror

Comment: I have. I actually played around with wrapping my call in an expect.not.toThrow() or an alternate option which was expecting the returned promise to resolve. This worked pretty well for any exceptions/rejections that happened directly in the called method. I commented below stating that the issue actually seems to be promise rejections deeper in the code that aren't being passed back up properly. Unfortunately I don't know if there's an easy solution to this problem other than to just refactor the code as we go.

Comment: I also wanted to note that after coming back to the issue, I was more clear as to why throwing the error inside of the `unhandledRejection` handler fails. Someone with more knowledge than me could probably better articulate why, but the `unhandledRejection` event handler gets triggered after the test has been ran. Throwing an error inside of it doesn't get caught because it's not technically within the context of a test anymore. The same thing happens if you use a `setTimeout` within a test, for example.

Comment: Did you find the answer? If so, could you share it, as I'm having the same problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Include the following content in [Jest's `setupFiles`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#setupfiles-array):

```js
if (!process.env.LISTENING_TO_UNHANDLED_REJECTION) {
  process.on('unhandledRejection', reason => {
    throw reason
  })
  // Avoid memory leak by adding too many listeners
  process.env.LISTENING_TO_UNHANDLED_REJECTION = true
}
```

Courtesy of [stipsan](https://github.com/stipsan) in https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/3251#issuecomment-299183885.

Comment: This should be the answer. Very helpful. I've tried to --trace-warning and run in rejection strict mode and neither would show me the offending LOC. This does! Thanks :)

Comment: It only shows the logs but does not fail the test.

Comment: For me to make it work I needed to remove the line:
`throw reason`

Answer (score 6):

The way I've approached this is very much tied into the way I write my functions - basically, any function that uses promises should return a promise. This allows whatever code calls that function to handle catching errors in any way it sees fit. Note that this is *my* approach and I'm not going to claim this is the only way to do things.

For example... Imagine I'm testing this function:

```
const myFunction = () => {
    return doSomethingWithAPromise()
        .then(() => {
            console.log('no problems!');
            return true;
        });
};
```

The test will look something like this:

```
describe('...', () => {
    it('...', () => {
        return myFunction()
            .then((value) => {
                expect(value).toBe(true);
            });
    });
});
```

Which works great. Now what happens if the promise is rejected? In my test, the rejected promise is passed back to Jest (because I'm returning the result of my function call) and Jest can report on it.

If, instead, your function does not return a promise, you might have to do something like this:

```
const myOtherFunction = () => {
    doSomethingWithAPromise()
        .then(() => {
            console.log('no problems!');
            return true;
        })
        .catch((err) => {
             // throw the caught error here
             throw err;
        });
};
```

Unlike the example above, there is no (direct) way for Jest to handle a rejected promise because you're not passing the promise back to Jest. One way to avoid this *might* be to ensure there is a `catch` in the function to catch & throw the error, but I haven't tried it and I'm not sure if it would be any more reliable.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I actually tried something similar. We're using `async/await` in our codebase, so I added an `await` in front of calling the method in question. This actually works great if a rejection comes back directly from the called method. Unfortunately due to some issues with how the code was written, the promises are rejecting deeper in the stack, and not being surfaced all the way back up to the method being called, and therefore can't be surfaced back to Jest.

Comment: Hmm... well if the errors are being "swallowed" somewhere deep in the code, it sounds like you may never be able to catch them :-/

Comment: It's definitely not ideal, and the solution might be to refactor the codebase so it's properly using Promises/async/await. In fact, that's why I'd like Jest to catch these, since then we can rely on CI to make sure we don't introduce more bad code to the system. The thing is that I'm actually able to catch those exceptions with the `uncaughtRejection` event. I just can't get Jest to see that as a failed test. 

Comment: My case is your second example @Kryten. How do you then tell Jest to expect `myOtherFunction` to throw an error?

Comment: jest is wack.  it's easy to add a promise rejection handler that fails tests in node

Answer (score 2):

module:

```
export function myPromise() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const error = new Error('error test');
    reject(error);
  });
}
```

test:

```
import { myPromise } from './module';


it('should reject the promise', () => {
  expect.assertions(1);

  const expectedError = new Error('error test');

  myPromise().catch((error) => {
    expect(error).toBe(expectedError);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

From the node documentation [site](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_events) we can see that `The process object is an instance of EventEmitter`.
Using the [emit](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_eventemitter) function from `process` we can trigger the errors like `uncaughtRejection` and `uncaughtException` programmatically when needed.

```
  it("should log the error", () => {
        process.emit("unhandledRejection");
        ...
        const loggerInfo = jest.spyOn(logger, "info");
        expect(loggerInfo).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is react code you are testing, you can intercept any unhandled errors by attaching an event handler to JSDOM's VirtualConsole's `jsdomError` event. This will let you spy the event and also prevent it from crashing jest.

```js
let jsdomError;

beforeEach(() => {
  jsdomError = jest.fn();
  window._virtualConsole.on('jsdomError',jsdomError);
});

afterEach(() => {
  window._virtualConsole.off('jsdomError',jsdomError);
});

test(() => {
  /* after you test everything */
  expect(jsdomError).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

I wrapped this up into an ErrorBoundary component that I use in my `@testing-library/react` tests.

```
export default class TestBoundary extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { error: false };
  }

  jsdomError = (err) => {
    this.componentDidCatch(err.detail, {});
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    window._virtualConsole.on('jsdomError', this.jsdomError);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window._virtualConsole.off('jsdomError', this.jsdomError);
  }

  componentDidCatch(error, { componentStack }) {
    const { onError } = this.props;
    this.setState({ error, componentStack });
    if (onError) {
      onError(error);
    } else {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { children, fallback } = this.props;
    const { error, componentStack } = this.state;

    if (!error) return children;

    if (isValidElement(fallback)) {
      return cloneElement(fallback, this.state);
    }

    if (typeof fallback === 'function') {
      return createElement(fallback, this.state);
    }

    return fallback || (
      <div data-testid="error">
        {error.stack || error.message}
        {'\n'}
        Components:
        {'\n'}
        {componentStack}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Not sure if this helps, but you can also assert for promise rejections as such

***index.js***

```
module.exports = () => {
  return Promise.reject('it didnt work');
}
```

***index.spec.js***

```
const thing = require('../src/index');

describe('rejected promise', () => {
  it('should reject with a reason', ()=> {

    return expect(thing()).rejects.toEqual('it didnt work');
   });
});
```